# Cosmos Gremlin API unique property value policy

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have several vertex types (labels), and for each of them i would like a unique property that would stop any additional vertex to be created with the same property. Think phone number for the phone vertices, business number for the organisation vertices, etc.

When i try to alter the indexing policy in my graph, it saves but then reverts back to the previous version. I can't seem to work this out... any assistance out there?

In Neo4J it's this:

```sql
CREATE CONSTRAINT book_isbn
FOR (book:Book)
REQUIRE book.isbn IS UNIQUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, simple answer... not possible. Any constraints, etc should be handled by a middle layer.